# match line break except line begin with spcific word or blank line

Tags: regex, notepad++

If I have text that the line breaks is broken:

```
Chapter 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci
ng elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut la
bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim ve
niam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labo ris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 


 Chapter 2

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci
ng elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut la
bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim ve
niam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labo ris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci
ng elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut la
bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim ve
niam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labo ris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

...
```

I want to restore the text by remove non necessary line breaks except the `chapter` line like this:

```
Chapter 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labo risnisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

 Chapter 2

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labo risnisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labo risnisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

...
```

I have try to match `(?<!Chapter\s\d)\n` and replace it with '' in notepad++, but it matches the Chapter lines (Why?). `(?<!Chapter\s\d)\n\r` or `(?<!Chapter\s\d)\r\n` also not working. So what regex can remove redundant line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\n)`

I used parentheses to capture the newline character.

https://regex101.com/r/zS9pB4/3

Comment: @TRX Check solution now.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zS9pB4/3 Ya, the match is OK now, but replacement add additional `space`s in result text. Do you know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: That actually isn't an extra space, it's just to show the user the location of the edit. :) For example, here I added a `-` in the location where the `\n` used to be https://regex101.com/r/zS9pB4/4 Is it fine now?